# Pycharm/IntelliJ shows 0% coverage for pytest even though coverage was generated

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, pytest, coverage.py

I have a Python project and a `tests` task, set up to run `pytest` from the project's working directory.

[image]

Doing `Run 'tests' with coverage` from the `Run` menu successfully runs the tests, and the console results shows that coverage was measured - e.g. 53% cover for `mws.py`.

[image]

The automatically applied coverage (as on the right) is 0% for all files, I'm not sure why. I'm using IntelliJ 2017.2.2 EAP.

NB: there is a related five year old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9841148/2387626), but the top rated solution there doesn't apply. There is no error message in the results console in this case.

Comment: Great question - your detailed process and screenshots were the answer to a different question I was struggling with :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the problem lies in you use `pytest-cov`, so Pycharm cannot parse the result which is shown in text like `53%` generated by `pytest-cov`;

So Changes option in `pytest.ini` to `addopts = -s -v` when you want to use Pycharm built in coverage tools.

In this command [`-v`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html#verbosity) stands for verbosity and [`-s`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html#how-to-capture-stdout-stderr-output) for disabling all output.

Comment: A really simple fix! Thank you! I can award the bounty in 5 hours

Comment: @AlmogCohen: I think the idea is to not use pytest-cov with PyCharm at all, just use `-s -v`. Not an optimal solution, admittedly.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar issue, but the accepted solution here didn't solve it.

I had `pytest` automatically run coverage in its configuration file.
In PyCharm, I added a Run Configuration to run all my tests with `pytest`.
It seemed to work, and I saw all tests running and got their results to display in PyCharm's run window.

But soon I noticed there were two problems:

1. When I selected "Run with coverage" I got an error like "coverage results not found", and all files showed 0% coverage.
2. Breakpoints in tests were not hit when running test in Debug mode.

Both problems disappeared when I added `--no-cov` to the "Additional Arguments" passed to to `pytest` (this option is in the Run Configuration).

So It seems the fix was to tell `pytest` to **not** run coverage when running it from PyCharm. Both "Run with coverage" option and the Breakpoints in tests now work.

Comment: Thanks
This worked without changing [tool.pytest.ini_options] in pyproject.toml

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me also - I didn't have [tool.pytest.ini_options] set at all

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my answer for other question about same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45729723/1229510

Basically if you use symlinks - coverage display won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is 2023 and your response is still relevant!